# Controller re-directing no where

Tags: cakephp

I am new to cakePHP,

I have an issue where selecting a controller does not seem to go anywhere by redirect back to the initial controller where from it was selected.

Are there any pointers of where i am probably meant to look.

be gentle please.

Comment: do you have acl implemented? is the action implemented? what url are you calling? what's your controller code?

Comment: this could be it....where might i find this?

Comment: found it...i dont thinks it is this :(

Comment: What do you mean by "selecting a controller"? Maybe check beforeFilter() method in this controller and in AppController.

Comment: sorry, as in a link in MVC directing e.g baseurl/controller/methodincontroller/, if i have a link going to say baseurl/controller/methodincontroller/ it doesnt move from its current page.

Comment: you're not being very clear... why don't you update the question with the actual url you're calling and the appropriate controller and let's start there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are being redirected back due to Auth Restrictions, lets go through some basic CakePHP to help you with your learning experience.

First lets makes it so your app will allow anyone to all your pages logged in or not

**In your /app/Controller/AppController.php, change your beforeFilter and isAuthorized function to be,** (Note: These are very basic setups to get you started)

```
public function beforefilter(){
  $this->Auth->allow();
}

public function isAuthorized(){
  return true;
}
```

Another reason why your App might be redirecting you is because your controller has no index function, open up your controller file to which you are trying to go to.

Example: If your trying to go to mysite.com/user then open /app/Controller/UserController.php and add the function below.

```
public function index(){

}
```

A good place for you to learn some CakePHP functions is http://cakephpcheatsheet.com/